# How to know a 2d list contains another list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, contains

I have a 2d list like indexList = [[1, A], [2, B], [3, C]...]. I need to check that this 2d list contains another list like item = [2, B] or not. I tried contains, listEquals, indexWhere but none of them works. In below, some examples of my code. How can I solve this?

**indexWhere example**

```
                         AppButton.buildAppButton(
                            context,
                            AppButtonType.BETSELECTION,
                            matchList[index][6],
                            kCategoryButtonDimensions,
                            color: tappedRowButtonIndex.indexWhere((test) =>
                                        test.contains([
                                          tappedRowIndex,
                                          tappedButtonIndex
                                        ])) !=
                                    null
                                ? Colors.yellow
                                : Colors.white,
```

**listEquals example**

```
                    AppButton.buildAppButton(
                            context,
                            AppButtonType.BETSELECTION,
                            matchList[index][6],
                            kCategoryButtonDimensions,
                            color: listEquals(tappedRowButtonIndex, [tappedRowIndex, tappedRowButtonIndex])
                                ? Colors.yellow
                                : Colors.white,
                            onPressed: () {
                              tappedRowIndex = index;
                              tappedButtonIndex = 3;
```

**contains example**

```
                      AppButton.buildAppButton(
                            context,
                            AppButtonType.BETSELECTION,
                            matchList[index][5],
                            kCategoryButtonDimensions,
                            color: tappedRowButtonIndex.contains(
                                    [tappedRowIndex, tappedButtonIndex])
                                ? Colors.yellow
                                : Colors.white,
                            onPressed: () {
                              tappedRowIndex = index;
                              tappedButtonIndex = 2;
```

Comment: Print your [`tappedRowIndex` ,`tappedButtonIndex`] like this and see if any of these value contains `tappedRowButtonIndex`

Comment: I prepared a simple example, it did not work. I can not see the mistake. List xx = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 3]], List yy = [1, 3], print('xx: ' + xx.toString()) => xx: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 3]], print('yy: ' + yy.toString()) => yy: [1, 3], print('3rd item in xx: ' + xx[2].toString()) => 3rd item in xx: [1, 3]; xx[2] == yy ? c = true : c = false; print(c) => c :false

Comment: try this code `List list1 = [1,'A']; List list2 = [2,'B']; List list3 = [3,'C']; List<List> dlist= [list1,list2, list3]; dlist.contains(list1) ? print('yes'): print('no');'

Comment: Your code is working, what is the difference?

Comment: Just use my code as example

Comment: @wierdo `xx[2].hashCode == yy.hashCode` is false in your code. They look identical but are actually different objects. On the other hand,`dlist[0].hashCode == list1.hashCode` is true in LonelyWolf's code because dlist[0] is list1 itself: `dlist= [list1, list2, list3];`